# turn on wifi using python

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I tried using this command in my Windows 10 command line:

`netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" enable`

..but it doesn't work, it just enables my wi-fi but doesn't turn it on.

I want to always keep my wi-fi turned on in my laptop. I also need my wi-fi to turn back on in just 2 minutes

Comment: Check Wireless Power Management settings in Window Power Management and make sure your Wireless card is set to maximum performance. My wireless card never stops.

Comment: It should never stop. Check your driver or add details about your wifi adapter to your post. Look also into the Event Viewer.

Comment: Here is a similar thread discussed on [Turn WiFi off using Python on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246527/turn-wifi-off-using-python-on-windows-10), it also include enable WiFi interface, you could have a look.